# Space between buttons on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-phone

I'm creating a game (minesweeper) for my Windows Phone.
There is a grid and this app automatically creates buttons (cells) by a double for loop (`i` for columns and `j` for rows).
The position of a button is `(CellWidth * i, CellHeigth * j, 0, 0)`.

The problem is the space between the buttons, and I don't know why it exist!
By code there isn't any space between the buttons.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you give some part of code?
Maybe your buttons inherit style from another base style?

Comment: The error is at line… oh, wait, you forgot to post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a style for the button and set the margin/padding to 0. I believe the default style has margins and/or padding.

Take a look at [Why does System.Windows.Controls.Button always have a padding of 10px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956728/why-does-system-windows-controls-button-always-have-a-padding-of-10px) and [How to remove the black space around the button in WP7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966232/how-to-remove-the-black-space-around-the-button-in-wp7)