# Button Background does not cover the entire button in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, windows-phone-8, background-image, styling

When I set a background to a button it does not cover the entire button. There is some offset or padding with background and button. How do I make the background cover entire Button?

```
<Button.Background >
   <ImageBrush  x:Name="LoginImg" source="fv.img" ></ImageBrush>
</Button.Background>
```

Comment: This seems to work, perhaps post some of your code? <Button Content="Test me" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/bg.jpg" />
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>

Comment: How do you set the background? Are you setting the content of the button?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd No I am setting the background of button as below <Button.Background >
                        <ImageBrush  x:Name="LoginImg" source="v" ></ImageBrush>
                    </Button.Background>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get into [button's style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966232/how-to-remove-the-black-space-around-the-button-in-wp7).
Or, probably, the easiest way (just workaround) is to use [negative padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956728/why-does-system-windows-controls-button-always-have-a-padding-of-10px).

Comment: Thanks :) Hey How do I do the same thing for stackpanel background as well?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're looking to, but try to play with stackpanel's Margin (it also can be negative, so it would stretch).

Comment: I am setting the background of the stackpanel in the same way